# Is there a name for this property?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, random-variables

I have written a proof that assumes a set of zero-mean vector-valued random variables $\mathcal{X}$ has the following property for some $q>2$:

There is a constant $c>0$ so that for each $X\in\mathcal{X}$ and any $k\times l$ matrix $A$ (where $l$ is the length of $X$), $E[\|AX\|_2^q]^{1/q}\leq \|A\Sigma A'\|_2^{1/2} c$, where $\Sigma$ is the variance-covariance matrix of $X$.

I know that this holds if $\mathcal{X}$ is a set of multivariate Gaussian random variables  in which case $c$ can be set to $E[\|Z\|^q]^{1/q}$ where $Z$ is a zero-mean Gaussian random vector of length $k$ and identity variance covariance matrix.

Comment: You can get properly spaced double norm bars using `\|`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use that from now on.